# Which encoding is used by the HTTP protocol?

Tags: http, http-headers, protocols, network-protocols

When a browser sends an HTTP request to a web server, what encoding is used to encode the HTTP protocol on the wire? Is it ASCII? UTF8? or UTF16? Or does it specify which encoding it uses in a predefined format (before any decoding takes place?)

P.S
I'm not asking about the actual payload (e.g. HTML) of the request/response. I'm asking about the request line (i.e. `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`) and headers (i.e. `Host: google.com`)

Answer (score 39):

HTTP 1.1 uses US-ASCII as basic character set for the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) in requests, the [status line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1) in responses (except the [reason phrase](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1)) and the [field names](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.1) but allows any octet in the field values and the [message body](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3).

Comment: By "field names" you mean http headers?

Comment: @OlegYablokov might be late to the party, but yes. According to [RFC 7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.2), "header-field" (just http header) is a pair of "field-name" and "field-value" separated by ":" and single optional space between ":" character and "field-value".

Answer (score 21):

[RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) includes this:

```
OCTET          = <any 8-bit sequence of data>
CHAR           = <any US-ASCII character (octets 0 - 127)>
UPALPHA        = <any US-ASCII uppercase letter "A".."Z">
LOALPHA        = <any US-ASCII lowercase letter "a".."z">
ALPHA          = UPALPHA | LOALPHA
DIGIT          = <any US-ASCII digit "0".."9">
CTL            = <any US-ASCII control character
                  (octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)>
CR             = <US-ASCII CR, carriage return (13)>
LF             = <US-ASCII LF, linefeed (10)>
SP             = <US-ASCII SP, space (32)>
HT             = <US-ASCII HT, horizontal-tab (9)>
<">            = <US-ASCII double-quote mark (34)>
```

And then pretty much everything else in the document is defined in terms of those entities (`OCTET`, `CHAR`, etc.). So you could look through the RFC to find out which parts of an HTTP request/response can include `OCTET`s; all other parts must be ASCII. (I'd do it myself, but it'd take a long time)

For the request line specifically, the method name and HTTP version are going to be ASCII characters only, but it's possible that the URL itself could include non-ASCII characters. *But* if you look at [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), it says that.

> A URI is a sequence of characters from a very limited set, i.e. the letters of the basic Latin alphabet, digits, and a few special characters.

Which I guess means that it'll consist of ASCII characters as well.