# How to set Japanes character in request Header

Tags: php, laravel, apache, request, http-headers

I am trying to set a custom header, everything works fine untill I set the header value with a Japanese string.[image]

Can anyone help me how to allow the Japanese value in header

System: Laravel + PHP 7 + Apache server

Comment: Try supply the URL-encoded version of those characters directly maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered in the link below. But the short answer is that it probably isn't going to work as HTTP headers were primarily designed with ASCII in mind. That said, if you control all the services end to end, you might be able to modify them to accept what you want.

[Can I use Unicode characters in HTTP headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567154/can-i-use-unicode-characters-in-http-headers)

Comment: After some investigation I ended up with same conclusion and as a solution encoding and decoding in some format is the only option. I went with encoding and decoding in base64 to solve the issue.