# Flask - headers are not converted to unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, flask, werkzeug, storm-orm

I'm developping a small web service in python using:

- Flask (v. 0.8)
- storm ORM (v. 0.19)
- Apache with mod_wsgi

I have a custom HTTP header, `Unison-UUID` which I'm using at some point to retrieve information in my database.

here's the (slightly rewritten for simplicity) snippet that I'm having trouble with:

```
uuid = flask.request.headers['Unison-UUID']
store = storm.locals.Store(my_database)
user = store.get(models.User, uuid)
```

The class `User` is more or less like this:

```
class User(Storm):
    uuid = Unicode(primary=True)
    # Other columns....
```

The code above fails in the following way:

```
  File "/Users/lum/Documents/unison-recsys/www/api/unison/unison.py", line 27, in decorated
    user = g.store.get(models.User, uuid)
  File "/Users/lum/Documents/unison-recsys/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/storm/store.py", line 165, in get
    variable = column.variable_factory(value=variable)
  File "/Users/lum/Documents/unison-recsys/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/storm/variables.py", line 396, in parse_set
    % (type(value), value))
TypeError: Expected unicode, found <type 'str'>: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000009'
```

I don't really understand why this is happening and what I can do about it. I thought [Flask was 100% unicode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/unicode/).

A quick fix I found is to decode the header value, i.e `uuid = uuid.decode('utf-8')`. Is this really what needs to be done? This seems a bit hackish. Is there no way to get unicode directly, without having to "decode" it manually?

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/818122/311220 http://stackoverflow.com/q/7567154/311220

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.request we read

> The request object is an instance of a `Request` subclass and provides
> all of the attributes Werkzeug defines.

The word `Request` links to http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Request where we read

> The `Request` and `Response` classes subclass the `BaseRequest` and
> `BaseResponse` classes and implement all the mixins Werkzeug provides:

The word `BaseRequest` links to http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest where we read

> headers
> The headers from the WSGI environ as immutable `EnvironHeaders`.

The word `EnvironHeaders` links to http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.EnvironHeaders where we read

> This provides the same interface as *Headers* and is constructed from a WSGI environment.

The word *Headers* is... no, it's not linked but it should has been linked to http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Headers where we read

> Headers is mostly compatible with the Python `wsgiref.headers.Headers` class

where the phrase `wsgiref.headers.Headers` links to http://docs.python.org/dev/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.headers.Headers where we read

> Create a mapping-like object wrapping headers, which must be a list of
> header name/value tuples as described in `PEP 3333`.

The phrase `PEP 3333` links to http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/ where there's no explicit definition of what type headers should be but after searching for word *headers* for a while we find this statement

> WSGI therefore defines two kinds of "string":
>
> ```
> "Native" strings (which are always implemented using the type named str)
> that are used for request/response headers and metadata
> "Bytestrings" (which are implemented using the `bytes` type in Python 3,
> and `str` elsewhere), that are used for the bodies of requests and
> responses (e.g. POST/PUT input data and HTML page outputs).
> ```

That's why in Python 2 you get headers as `str` not `unicode`.

Now let's move to decoding.

Neither your `.decode('utf-8')` nor mensi's `.decode('ascii')` (nor blindly expecting any other encoding) is universally good because [In theory, HTTP header field values can transport anything; the tricky part is to get all parties (sender, receiver, and intermediates) to agree on the encoding.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7568675/95735). Having said that I think you should act according to Julian Reshke's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7568675/95735)

> Thus, the safe way to do this is to stick to ASCII, and choose an encoding on top
> of that, such as the one defined in RFC 5987.

after checking that User Agents (browsers) you support have implemented it.

Title of [RFC 5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987) is *Character Set and Language Encoding for Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Header Field Parameters*

Answer (score 0):

Header values are ASCII, see the linked questions by Acorn.

What you can do here is either decode it manually like you did (although you should use `uuid.decode('ascii')` and not utf-8) or change your field to be `RawStr` instead of `Unicode`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `RawStr`. This might indeed be a better choice in my specific case.