# Can the header field of requests.post be a unicode object?

Tags: python, unicode, python-requests

I'm using python requests 2.2.1, and trying to post a request with a custom header.

I'm creating my own header, `myheader`, like this:

```
myheader = {'name' : myvalue }
```

The thing is `myvalue` is a unicode object. I'm not encoding it to a byte string, just directly putting it in the `myheader` dictionary.

and when I do:

```
r = requests.post(myhost, headers=myheader)
```

I get an exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 17-18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And I guess I could get rid of it by doing `myvalue.encode('utf8')` before putting it in the `header` dictionary - but my question is, is it illegal then to put a unicode object in the header?  I ask because the response can contain unicode objects with no problem, so why can I not put one in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers are **not** unicode data, no. They are not part of the POST body (which is encoded for you as needed, and can otherwise contain *any* binary data).

The vast majority of HTTP headers encode information that only require the ASCII characterset *anyway*. For example, an `Accept-Language` header only contains ISO-639 language codes, with optional ISO-3166 country codes, plus `q`, `;`, `=` and numeric information.

It is generally accepted that HTTP headers *may* also contain Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) characters (so up to Unicode U+00FF); specifically the [HTTP 1.1 Warning header specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.46) uses Latin-1 as the default. If you need to encode text in a header outside of the Latin-1 range, encode the text following [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047). In Python, you can do so with [`email.header.Header()` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html#email.header.Header):

```
from email.header import Header

myheader = {'name': str(Header(u'Some unicode value', 'utf-8'))}
```

Comment: is there an advantage to using `email.header` over just doing `someunicodevalue.encode('utf8')`?

Comment: @patchwork: it is standards-compliant, meaning that it should work with *any* HTTP server and not get rejected because the header can't be decoded as Latin-1.

Comment: I have a client, written in python using Flask, that receives the request. But when I retrieve the headers using the flask definition of an HTTP request, I am given unicode objects. Not a big problem, but confusing in the light of your answer (which I have accepted)

Comment: @patchwork: yes, the Werkzeug request objects automatically decode headers to Unicode values, by decoding as Latin-1. Or rather, headers are left as passed in from the WSGI environment, which on Python 3, means unicode values decoded from Latin-1.

Comment: @patchwork: related:  [Flask - headers are not converted to unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10124786)